# I am getting EXC_GUARD when launching app using NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath

Tags: objective-c, exception, crash, file-descriptor, nstask

Faulting code:

```
myTask = [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath: appPath arguments: initArray];
```

Where myTask is a global `static NSTask* myTask = NULL;` and initArray is a global `static NSMutableArray *initArray = NULL;` and appPath is a local NSString*

```
Exception Type:        EXC_GUARD
Exception Codes:       0x4000000200000001, 0x326e91a2a5c769eb
Exception Subtype:     GUARD_TYPE_FD, id=0x326e91a2a5c769eb, fd=1, flavor=0x00000002 (DUP)
```

Top of stack:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2033848e dup + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2126df14 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:error:] + 2491
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff21294c89 +[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:arguments:] + 146
```

This issue is not reproducible and this code has not been changed since years. Please suggest some ways to debug this.

**Additional info:** Parent app which is launching this task has its output stream and error stream set to a log file but both the streams have been set after this app gets launched.

Comment: I don't understand. Is `initArray` nil when called? Because according to the doc, it should raises an exception: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstask/1414375-launchedtaskwithlaunchpath

Comment: initArray is not null. It has arguments that needs to be passed to mytask.